# how to transform pandas dataframe by type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have python dataframe like below

```
      index            date hour    type    tiantan
2014-01-01 00:00:00 20140101    0   PM2.5   32.0
2014-01-01 00:00:00 20140101    0   PM10    110.0
2014-01-01 01:00:00 20140101    1   PM2.5   56.0
2014-01-01 01:00:00 20140101    1   PM10    126.0
```

I would like to transform to below format, what's the best way archive this?

```
  index            date     hour    pm25    pm10
2014-01-01 00:00:00 20140101    0   32.0    110.0
2014-01-01 01:00:00 20140101    1   56.0    126
```

Comment: What is the logic behind changing the column "type, tiantan" to "pm25, pm10"? Please modify your question to make it more precise.

Answer (score 2):

Given a dataframe *df*, you can use the Pandas function *pivot* to pivot the dataformat to wide.

Using your columns, this pivot can be done by calling pandas 'pivot' on the dataframe using 'tiantan' as the value column as indicated in the *values* argument:

```
   df.pivot(columns = 'type', values = 'tiantan')
```

Comment: If you want to keep index, date and hour columns, you can add them as indices and reset the index.
 df.pivot(index = ['index', 'date', 'hour'], columns = 'type', values = 'tiantan')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.columns.name = None